Boot Freeze on Dell Latitude 5400 After GRUB Menu
After the grub menu the boot freezes with the dell logo and this text at the top
EFI stub: Loaded initrd from LINUX_INITRD_MEDIA_GUID device path
EFI stub: Measured initrd data into PCR 9
Right now the only ways I can access the PC is through recovery mode or settings acpi=off in the grub menu.
Update:
Adding the acpi=off disables my soundcard (I can see it listed with lshw but it does not appear in the settings also there's no battery information anymore.
System Info:
Model: Dell Latitude 5400
Processor: Intel Core i7-8365U CPU @ 1.80GHz
RAM: 8 GB DDR4
Storage: 256 GB SSD
Graphics: Intel UHD Graphics

Why is using the acpi=off a problem. Many do this.

When in this mode my soundcard does not work and I can't see the battery information.

Please add that to the question.

@DavidDE I have done that. Do you think this is fixable?

I am assuming that it has never worked? Boot form the install Media and use the try option and see if you have same issue.  Since you are using the latest as of today version of Ubuntu some actual hardware info may be helpful.

I still have the same issue with the install media. Updating question with system information.

@DavidDE I made a new live USB and now I can boot from it. What do I do next?

Step by step guide https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

It seems you're suggesting that I should reinstall Ubuntu. This would be the third time I am doing it and it does not fix the issue.

Try 22.04 and see if same issue.
